# scala case class with synthetic val

Tags: scala

The [documentation page for case classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html) states

> Case classes are good for modeling immutable data

Would be any risk/disadvantage to have a *synthetic* val in a case class like

```
case class Square(val side: Int) {
    val area = side * side
}
```

Comment: No, it would not have any problems. It is perfectly fine to do that. Do you have a specific concern about it? - BTW, the Scala [**Gitter channel**](https://gitter.im/scala/scala) is a better place for this kind of questions.

Comment: It evaluates when you create the case class, with lazy val or def it only evaluates when it is needed, not a disadvantage if you want the value right away. Depends.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez not in particular, though I'm still learning scala and I'm not sure if there are any side effects for such use case for case classes. Thank you for suggestion, I wasn't aware of Gitter channel

Comment: won't be taken in account by code based on case class `apply`/`unapply` (such as most of the macros)

Comment: @ValentinCarnu Ok, no problem. As cchantep said, the only _"downside"_ is that it will not be used in `toString, equals, hashCode, productIterator` and all the other method generated by the case classes. However, for `hashCode` and `equals`, since it is deterministically created from other inputs, it won't affect. For `toString` you can always override it. The only big problem is `productIterator` or macros, but since it is always recreated, it may not be too much of a problem. - On the other hand, having to specify both the side and the area of a square on creation seems bad design to me.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thank you for details, I was missing the concerns regarding the 'productIterator' and the macros, I'll consider them while designing my classes. If you want to type that as an answer I will accept it

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez regarding the `area` being passed as parameter I agree and my biggest concern is that using `copy` method the area could be changed and it will result in a square with a wrong area

Comment: @ValentinCarnu exactly, IMHO your design is _"good"_. The only problem would be if you need to include `area` on some kind of auto-generated output from your class. For example, you want to include that field in a **JSON** representing your data, which will be sent to other service. And you dice to use **Circe** to automatically encode them. `area` will not be included by default, but you can _"easily"_ customize your codec to do so. - In resume, unless you really need it to be a parameter _(which will have its own problems)_, leaving it as derived value is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue with defining an additional `val` in the `case class` body but keep in mind that this value will not be treated in any special way by the compiler, as opposed to the values that are part of the constructor.

This means that it won't be used in the implementations of methods like `hashCode`, `equals`, `toString`, `copy` and others from the `Product` which all case classes implicitly extend.

In the case of a value that is completely defined by other values from the constructor, like `area` here, this is of course completely fine. I would even argue that is the only correct choice, because `area` as a constructor parameter of `Square` would make it redundant with `side`, and every compiler-generated method would have to uselessly deal with `area`. It would also allow to pick areas that don't match `side`.

Note that declaring `area` as a `val` computes it only once, and then the value is stored, which makes every `Square` instance a bit larger in memory. You could also decide to declare it as a `def` to compute it every time you need it. For `area`, you only do a simple multiplication, so it probably doesn't matter, but it does in more complex scenarios.

Also note that, as far as I know, the *synthetic vals* terminology is usually reserved for values that are compiler-generated.